# Join 2 tables with with mutiple keys in Azure ML Studio

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I have two datasets with multiple columns. I would like to join the two tables with the following keys: zip code, year, month, data, hour

However whenever I use a **Join Module** on these two tables, the Join doesn't happen, and I just get a Table with Columns from Right Table with empty values.

Here is the R equivalent of what I am trying to do:

```
YX <- leftTableDT
YX %<>% merge( rightTableDT, all.x = TRUE, by=c('zip','year','month','day','hour') )
```

Any ideas on why Join Module in Azure ML Studio doesn't work for multiple keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double-check that you've selected "Allow duplicates and preserve column order in selection" in column selection options, so it matches the columns in listed order.

Also, you could try Apply SQL Transformation module to join datasets.